# Open a webpage for 20s then close it, daily

Tags: windows

Work has a requirement for certain employees to open a web-page and 'browse around'. Luckily they only register once you first access the site. Is there a way to create a windows script to open a webpage for 20s, then close it?

I think I can get the webpage to load with a service or something in Windows, no idea how to force close it after a period of time though??

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Windows and cannot try it, but I think the simplest method is to use internal Windows scheduler.

1. schedule a task to open your page:
   firefox -new-tab "https://www.visit_me.com"
2. schedule another task that should run after 20 seconds to kill the browser:
   taskkill /im firefox.exe

The only disadvantage is that if you use firefox at that moment, it will be closed with your tabs as well. But you can duplicate firefox.exe to firefox_mytask.exe and use this clone in the scheduler to do what you need.